# Como fazer para abrir o link na mesma aba

Tags: html

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<form method='post' action='https://cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/transactional/order/buynow' target='blank'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' /><input type='image' name='submit' alt='TESTAR' /></form>
```

Ele abre uma nova aba com a tela de pagamento da cielo, eu queria que quando aperta o botão, ele abre abrir a tela na mesma aba, e não abrir uma nova aba.

Comment: Você poderia só omitir o `target` pois o valor default é `_self`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta mudar o target do seu link.

```
<a href="#" target="_self">Link</a>
```

Comment: vlw,so meio lerdo '-'